# Sitecore 6.6 Shell Excel Uploader

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

A sitecore instance was recently upgraded from 6.1 to 6.6. There was an upload command that opened a custom xaml dialog. This had an upload button on it which would open another modal with:

```
UploadPackageForm.Show(MyConstants.FolderPath, true);
```

While testing some points of functionality across the site I ran into an error while using this uploader saying that the file being uploaded needs to be a zip file. I'm guessing that somewhere along the way from 6.1 to 6.6 the package uploader was given a check for the file type being uploaded. I've been looking around for dialogs that sitecore comes with that I may be able to use. These look promising:

I can't seem to get the file path from this one although I think I could set a property on args passed into the OnOK event which I will try tomorrow.

```
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.AddFilesDialog
```

I'm not sure how I would show this one:

```
Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Dialogs.Upload
```

Another option is to try making a custom dialog. Any thoughts and ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look around the code that deals with the file explorer (that does not restrict the upload file type) and found this. Might be useful:

```
public static void UploadToDirectory(string directory)
{
  Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) directory, "directory");
  Error.AssertString(directory, "directory", true);
  UrlString urlString = new UrlString("/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/Upload/Upload.aspx");
  urlString.Append("di", directory);
  Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlString.ToString(), "files:uploaded");
}
```

This method is in `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Files` in `Sitecore.Kernel`

Comment: That looks pretty solid. I'll try that out right now.

Comment: This looks pretty good. I'm going to look around for a way to get the first file name that was uploaded since I want to populate the dialog before the upload dialog with that file.

Comment: Great. I'd recommend decompiling `Sitecore.Client.Dll` and finding references to that class.

Answer (score 1):

Is the upload for site visitors or Sitecore users within a Sitecore app?  Regardless, the UploadPackageForm, in 6.6, validates that the file is a valid Sitecore package (which is always a ZIP file).  6.1 didn't do this.

DOn't use the AddFilesDialog as that's also within the context of installing a Sitecore app.

I'm not exactly sure what the upload is for but if it's for the rendered site, you should create your own.  If it's for a Sitecore app, there are several depending on what you need.  There's the FlashUpload (3 types under /sitecore/shell/Applications/FlasUpload), the Media uploads at /sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/Upload****.

Comment: I'll check some of those out. It is for content editors to upload excel files which can then be used to create items based on each row of the file.